# How do I turn off the little display icons for `SparseArray`, `InterpolatingFunction` and so on?

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, elided-forms

As noted elsewhere, in Mathematica 10.x, many functions that return "opaque" objects display them as cute little icons:

> ```
> In[1]:= NDSolveValue[{x''[t] == -Sin[x[t]], x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 10}]
> ```
>
> `Out[1]=` [image: cute little icon]

Neat as they are, I've found that they can often take a ferociously long time to render when you have a large expression involving (say) many terms with `InterpolatingFunctions`. I would like to be able to give up the aesthetic frills in return for not having enough time to wax my car every time I forget to stick a semicolon at the end of an `NDSolve`. Is there a way (perhaps a preference setting) of accomplishing this, preferably one that doesn't involve (say) having answers all come out in `OutputForm` or something?

Comment: I think there's answer on site...Not sure if I can find it.  And I think there is a way to do it.  Or I'm dreaming. :)

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55015

Comment: Could you send a notebook that shows the *ferociously long time to render* to the support? That would help to track down what if anything needs to be fixed.

Comment: @user21 That's a great idea; I'll try to get to it today.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The old typesetting can be restored by

```
SetSystemOptions["TypesetOptions" -> "IconicElidedForms" -> False];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also mentioned previously: [(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72699/), [(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55012/), [(3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71806).

Comment: Is that the technical name? "IconicElidedForms"?

Comment: @belisariushassettled I think so. Internally these are sometimes called "summary boxes" or even blobs.

Comment: Yup, this did the trick!