# How to control the output of Polygon

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, elided-forms

In the documentation article for `Polygon` in Mathematica 12, there is an example with the input:

```
pol = Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}]
```

In the documentation article the output is displayed as:

> ```
> Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}]
> ```

But when I evaluate the code I get a different output with some information about the polygon, the number of points, the dimension, and more. It looks like this:

[image: polygon]

Is there a way to control what is obtained as output?

Comment: Try applying InputForm or the more verbose FullForm to the polygon.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is what I sometimes need. Is this new feature in version 12?

Comment: No FullForm/InputForm have been there forever since 1988 - these bubble things with info have been there in the last few versions at least. It would be nice if there was an option to turn off these front-end bubble forms which also appear for SparseArray, ProbabilityDistribution, ClassifierFunction, InterpolationFunction etc.

Comment: I jumped from version 8 to version 12. The "bubble things" were an unpleasant surprise.  Thank you flinty for answering my question with your comment. Why don't you post your comment as an answer? Although simple, it was very useful to me.

Comment: see Lukas Lang's comment on m_goldberg's answer - ```BoxForm`UseIcons = False``` seems to work though it's a protected symbol so you need to unprotect it to change it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The examples in the documentation article for `Polygon` should have been re-evaluated before Mathematica 12 was released, but it is evident that they weren't. This is true even for V12.1.1. If you manually evaluate the examples shown in the documentation they will show the new iconized argument form. This is a documentation bug,

That said, you can get the old output form like this:

```
pol = Defer @ Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}]
```

> ```
> Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}]
> ```

Comment: Do you know of any way (global options?) to turn off iconization in the front-end?

Comment: @flinty. I do not.

Comment: @flinty You can use ``With[{prot = Unprotect@BoxForm`UseIcons}, BoxForm`UseIcons = False; Protect /@ prot;]`` to turn the summary forms off for some cases, including `Polygon`.

Comment: @Lukas, it is safer to use `SetSystemOptions["TypesetOptions" -> {"IconicElidedForms" -> False}]` instead of the `Unprotect[]` business.

Comment: @flinty, see the above comment as well.

Comment: @J.M. now that was really helpful. The iconized polygons have been bugging me often, and I did not find the option you showed. Do you think a new question with your comment as an answer would have merit?

Comment: @Yves, [I actually picked it up from ilian.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99917). The only problem is that that option globally affects all elided forms, and not just `Polygon[]`. I don't know if elided forms can be selectively turned off. Perhaps that one, you can ask.

Comment: @J.M. thank you for the clarification. I´ll give it some thought. In any case, thanks for the fix - this drove me mad, as I do tend to have lots of polygons lying around at any time.

Answer (score 4):

Following the comments under m_goldberg Answer to this question (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/227859) the following code disables the SummaryBox for `Polygon` only without disabling all elided forms or modifying the protected symbol `` BoxForm`UseIcons ``:

```
ClearAll[Region`PolygonDump`summaryBox]
Region`PolygonDump`summaryBox[poly_, format_] :=  ToBoxes[InputForm@poly, format]
Region`PolygonDump`summaryBox[___] := $Failed
Attributes[Region`PolygonDump`summaryBox] = {HoldAllComplete};
```

[image: Disablingthe SummaryBox for Polygon]

`` Region`PolygonDump`summaryBox `` is the internal function constructing the SummaryBox for `Polygon` which I found using `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions[Polygon] ``. I have not noticed any problems using this but unwanted side effects might occur when modifying core functions and the internal functionality for `BoxForm` of `Polygon` might change in the future but the presented solution works for me in 12.1.1.0.